# I can't manage to make an api call using a parsed integer

Tags: android, rest, flutter, dart, mobile

So I am building an app using flutter, I am new to flutter and would need help on a little something.

So for the context, my app is connected to a REST API, which was tied to a ruby on rails web app for a fictional elevators company (for learning purposes) and what I am trying to achieve is to change the status of an elevator using a text field in my app, I almost got it, the only thing is that whenever I do my api call like this:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo.
  final Elevator elevator;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.elevator}) : super(key: key);

  Future _changeStatus(elevator) async {
    //Fetch the data from the api
    // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    var id = elevator.id.toString();
    var holder = id.toString();
    var url = 'https://rocketcrybaby.azurewebsites.net/api/elevators/'+holder;
    var response = await http.put(
        url, body: {'status': '${_statusController.text}'});
    if (_statusController.text != "active"|| _statusController.text != "inactive"){
      return "Error not a valid status !";
    }
    print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');

    //print(await http.read('https://example.com/foobar.txt'));
   return "sucess";
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the Todo to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Elevator # " +elevator.id.toString()),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _statusController
          ),
        )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async => [ await _changeStatus(elevator.id.toString()), print(elevator.status)]),


    );
  }
```

it returns me this error:

```
 E/flutter (18441): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'id'.
E/flutter (18441): Receiver: "3"
E/flutter (18441): Tried calling: id
```

I really don't know what to do anymore I tried every trick I had in my book :/

for reference here's the Elevator class

```
class Elevator {
  final String status;
  final String model;
  final int id;

  Elevator({this.status, this.model, this.id}); //Elevator Constructor

  factory Elevator.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) { //Parse the infos as Json String
    return Elevator(
      status: json['status'],
      model: json['model'],
      id: json['id']
    );
  }


}
```

Additionally here's the output of an elevator in my api

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "column_id": 1,
        "serial_number": 7204019747089,
        "model": "Excelium",
        "building_type": "Hybrid",
        "status": "Inactive",
        "date_service_since": "2018-03-09T00:00:00",
        "date_last_inspection": "2019-02-19T00:00:00",
        "inspection_certificate": "Yes",
        "information": "Dori",
        "notes": "Dolores aut et. Ea optio rem. Provident exercitationem ut.",
        "created_at": "2020-04-09T20:41:55",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-09T20:41:55"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo.
  final Elevator elevator;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.elevator}) : super(key: key);

  Future _changeStatus(Elevator  elevator) async {
    //Fetch the data from the api
    // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    var id = elevator.id.toString();
    var holder = id.toString();
    var url = 'https://rocketcrybaby.azurewebsites.net/api/elevators/'+holder;
    var response = await http.put(
        url, body: {'status': '${_statusController.text}'});
    if (_statusController.text != "active"|| _statusController.text != "inactive"){
      return "Error not a valid status !";
    }
    print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');

    //print(await http.read('https://example.com/foobar.txt'));
   return "sucess";
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the Todo to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Elevator # " +elevator.id.toString()),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _statusController
          ),
        )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async => [ await _changeStatus(elevator), print(elevator.status)]),


    );
  }
```

Tip: Always use Variable type while declaring the variable to avoid these errors and for good practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your method : `Future _changeStatus(elevator) async` actually takes `Elevator elevator`, but you are providing `elevator.id.toString()` which is a String.

Change the method parameter's type and in FAB's onPressed change to await `_changeStatus(elevator)`.